# How to get user's state In USA

Tags: swift, xcode

How can I get the state the user lives in?

My code:

```
let geoCoder = CLGeocoder()
        geoCoder.reverseGeocodeLocation(currentUserLocation) { (placemarks, error) -> Void in

            if error != nil {
                print("Error getting location: \(error)")
            } else {
                let placeArray = placemarks as [CLPlacemark]!
                var placeMark: CLPlacemark!
                placeMark = placeArray?[0]
                let result = placeMark.addressDictionary
                let cityName = result?["City"] as! String
                print(cityName)
            }
        }
```

Comment: try : `if let stateName = result?["State"] as? String{ }`

Answer (score 0):

[CLPlacemark documentation](https://developer.apple.com/reference/corelocation/clplacemark)

> var administrativeArea: String?
>
> The state or province associated with the placemark.

```
print(placeMark.administrativeArea)
```

No need to access the dictionary.